# To communate between A fragment and B fragment on MainActivity

Tags: android, fragment, communication, android-fragmentactivity

I'm struggling on those work

1. Question

   > ## Between A fragment and B fragment , When click event happen on A fragment, How can i set B fragment's view
2. IDE : Android Studio
3. TargetFragments 
   A. NavigationDrawer Fragment

   - For Left NavigationDrawer Menu ..

   B. Placeholder Fragment

   - When click event happen on NavigationDrawer
   - ,set TextView on FrameLayout(from MainActivity)
4. What i want

   - When click event happen at a Fragment(For Navigation Drawer),
   - I want to set a Textview from another fragment(PlaceholderFragment)
   - which bound to FrameLayout on MainActivity's Layout
5. What i have done :

   1) At a Callback(from Navigation Drawer fragment), getting PlaceholderFragment's 
   TextView(section_label)

   ```
   @Override
   public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
       // update the main content by replacing fragments

      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1), "MY_FRAGMENT"+(position + 1))
           .commit();        

   Log.d("INFO","MY_FRAGMENT"+(position + 1));

      TextView LabelText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.section_label);
      LabelText.setText("Its works i think");
     // 클릭 이벤트가 발생했을경우 내용을 가져와서 별도 처리하는 부분 ....

   Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "HelloWorld", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
   ```

   2) onCreate , getting ViewText , Setting

   ```
    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

   mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
           getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
   mTitle = getTitle();


   Log.d("INFO","OnCreate진입");
   //RelativeLayout some = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.fragment_my);

    TextView LabelText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    LabelText.setText("Its works i think");


   // Set up the drawer.
   mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
           R.id.navigation_drawer,
           (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));


   }
   ```
6. Result

   - All they return "Null"

Comment: It is usually recommended to use interfaces to communicate between fragments.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment, define an Interface and give it a method to send the data:

```
public interface Communicator{
    public void sendData(String data);
}
```

Then, in your activity, implement your Interface

```
...MyActivity implements Communicator{
```

Instantiate your FragmentB:

```
FragmentB fb = new FragmentB();
```

Override the method:

```
public void sendData(String data){
    //Do something with data
    fb.changeData(data);
}
```

In FragmentB, define a method called changeData:

```
public void changeData(String data){
    textview.setText(data);
}
```

Comment: Ok, then where should i instaniate my FragmentB?
like this? in MainActivity should i make a field? 
private FragmentB mFb = new FragmentB()?

Comment: It would probably be best to initialize FragmentB as a private variable in your MainActivity and instantiate it in onCreate or another method called before sendData.

Comment: Thanks it helped me but I solved deference way , bc when click happens in FragmentA it's callback called before onCreate() at Acitivity so I couldn't get proper View in there. At that moment I just initialize FragmentB and right away when I try to search textView in FragmentB it return Null ,

Comment: So what I did is that , in fragmentB at onAttach I just got Activity as parameter , then onStart() I can manage my text view or onCreateView() I just can manage any view without activity parameter therefore I can manage click action from FragmentA to FragmentB